# Calculate the volume of a shape between two planes

Tags: python, geometry, volume, nifti

I have a shape in 3D, that is represented by a point cloud (blue points in the picture). Specifically, I am working with MRI data where each point is one voxel with a specific segmentation label. This cloud is intersected by two planes, parallel to one another. I want to find the volume of the shape formed by the points between the two planes (orange in the picture).

My initial approach was to just “count the points between the planes”, i.e. all the voxels that are at least partly contained, but this isn’t an exact volume calculation, since some voxels are intersected by the plane and thus are only partly contained. For example if a voxel is intersected by the plane so that half of it is below the plane, then I want to count that 0.5 in my volume calculation instead of counting the whole voxel.

I’ve looked into convex and concave hulls, but i don’t think this is the right approach for me since I’m only interested in the exact number of voxels that are between the planes and using a convex hull would falsify the volume.

Is there a better way to do this than to loop through all the voxels and compute exactly where the plane intersects them ? Or does anyone know of an existing implementation of this, ideally in python ?

[picture of the data and the planes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYrZN.png)

Comment: Is the point cloud represented by a set of (x,y,z) voxel coordinates, or by the voxel array itself?   Are the planes that bound the region of interest always parallel?   Always aligned with two of the axes?

Comment: The points are represented by (x,y,z) coordinates and the planes are parallel to one another but not necessarily to two of the axes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking the next easiest approach to get a better number without having to do a bunch of extra brute force math. On average any voxel intersected will be cut in the middle. If quite a few are cut then this assumption will likely be true and you simply count all touching the planes as half of their volume.

Comment: I've also tried resampling the data to a higher resolution to get a more accurate estimation, but I'd like to have some value to compare these to. The idea would be to have a "true" reference volume to be able to see the resolution I have to resample to, in order to get a good enough approximation.